# Efficient serialization/deserialization of huffman tree

Tags: huffman-coding

I have implemented huffman encoding in the form

```
struct node
{
    node * left;
    node * right;
    double freq; // the frequency
    string letter;
    string binary_code; // the variable length code
};
```

that works fine, eg:

```
Data: electric eels
Compressed: -σ» //doesnt render in this text editor sorry
Decompressed: electric eelss
Ratio: 38%
```

But I have no idea how to efficiently encode the tree itself (needed for the decompression) to send over socket, and then decode it.

Can someone help me with some c code/pseudocode style explanation?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to build [Canonical Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code) from the frequencies and use it to encode the data.

Canonical Huffman code can be encoded in a pretty compact way, as was described in the [ZIP APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) file, look for words Shannon-Fano and Huffman.

You can find C code in any deflate/inflate implementation or [Huff0](https://github.com/Cyan4973/FiniteStateEntropy).

Comment: Thanks,
wouldn't deserialization be O(n^2) then? as you'd have to loop over each code and each character in encoded string.
It feels like there would be a O(n*m + log(n)) solution for some reason